# AngularJS Scroll to Top when route changes, anchorScroll show in url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing, anchor-scroll

i have two main problems with my angularJS Webapp.

1. I want that the browser is scrolling to top when
   the route is chaning (or the page is changing) - currently
   its remebering the position - thats kinda annoying.
2. I have a onepage with 3 different tabs on the subpages.
   I can navigate through them with a ng-click function and smoth scrolling (anchor)

My Problem is, that i want to have this anchor tags show up in the url 
Like: about/section1   about/section2  about/section3

Currently all is staying at "about"

Here is my Setup:

```
// 3 Ng click funtions to navigate in the submenue to the sections (all in one page) - but they not showing up in the url tag! 

    angular.module('testApp')
      .value('duScrollDuration', 2000)
      .value('duScrollOffset', 122)
      .controller('ankerCtrl', function($scope, $document){

        var container = angular.element(document.getElementById('container'));
        $scope.toTheTop = function() {
          container.scrollTop(0, 5000);

        }
        $scope.toSection1 = function() {
          console.log("hallooo ich will zu section 1");
          var someElement = angular.element(document.getElementById('section-1'));
          $document.scrollToElementAnimated(someElement);
        }
        $scope.toSection2 = function() {
          console.log("hallooo ich will zu section 2");
          var someElement = angular.element(document.getElementById('section-2'));
          $document.scrollToElementAnimated(someElement);
        }
        $scope.toSection3 = function() {
          console.log("hallooo ich will zu section 3");

          var someElement = angular.element(document.getElementById('section-3'));
          $document.scrollToElementAnimated(someElement);
        }
      }
    );

//Routing
.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $anchorScrollProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('about', {
        url: "/about",
        views: {
          'content': {
            templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
          },
          'subnavi': {
            templateUrl: 'views/subnavi-about.html'
          }
        }
      }).state('unternehmen', {
        url: "/unternehmen",
        views: {
          'content': {
            templateUrl: 'views/unternehmen.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
          },
          'subnavi': {
            templateUrl: 'views/subnavi-unternehmen.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('main', {
        url: "/",
        views: {
          'content': {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
          }
        }
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling();

  });
```

Thanks alot for your help!

(again: 
1. Scroll to top
2. Subanchors dont show up in the url tag

Comment: Does it have to scroll to top, or an specific element on the same page?

Comment: nope - currently not. I thought there might be a gernera rule, like "if the route changes - scroll to top "